# How to solve a problem with circular dependancy in C and function pointers

Tags: c, pic

|In a program I use this struct with function pointers but I want to change it so I can save, restore and replace the function pointers with one single statement.

```
typedef struct MenuStr
{
       // more elements
       uint8_t (*ButtonUpPtr)(struct MenuStr *Menu);
       uint8_t (*ButtonDownPtr)(struct MenuStr *Menu);
       uint8_t (*ButtonLeftPtr)(struct MenuStr *Menu);
       uint8_t (*ButtonRightPtr)(struct MenuStr *Menu);
       uint8_t (*PreMenuCursorPtr)(struct MenuStr *Menu);
       uint8_t (*MenuCursorPtr)(struct MenuStr *Menu);
       uint8_t (*PostMenuCursorPtr)(struct MenuStr *Menu);
       // more elements
}MENU;
```

Therefore I want to change the above into allowing a copy of all the pointers with one statement.

```
typedef struct Cursorstr
{
       uint8_t (*ButtonUpPtr)(struct MenuStr *Menu);
       uint8_t (*ButtonDownPtr)(struct MenuStr *Menu);
       uint8_t (*ButtonLeftPtr)(struct MenuStr *Menu);
       uint8_t (*ButtonRightPtr)(struct MenuStr *Menu);
       uint8_t (*PreMenuCursorPtr)(struct MenuStr *Menu);
       uint8_t (*MenuCursorPtr)(struct MenuStr *Menu);
       uint8_t (*PostMenuCursorPtr)(struct MenuStr *Menu);
}CURSOR_STR;

typedef struct MenuStr
{
           // more elements
           CURSOR_STR  Elements;
           // more elements
}MENU;
```

Now I stumble into a problem with the arguments of the pointers and I can not find the solution. 
Assistance is appreciated

Comment: Do some research about *forward declarations*.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude  Even after adjusting the forward declarations to the level indicated by Lundin i still have the same . With a different argument on the functions used (no forward declarations) I have a lot of warnings ofcourse but the program compiles and runs. There must be more

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll have to forward-declare the `MENU` struct. Add this before the declaration of `CURSOR_STR`:

```
typedef struct MenuStr MenuStr;
```

All this does is to tell the compiler that there will be a struct called `MenuStr` in the program, but that it will be defined later on.

---

Also consider using a typedef for the function pointers. Full example:

```
typedef struct MenuStr MenuStr;

typedef uint8_t ButtonFunc (MenuStr*);

typedef struct Cursorstr
{
  ButtonFunc* ButtonUpPtr;
  ButtonFunc* ButtonDownPtr;
  ButtonFunc* ButtonLeftPtr;
  ButtonFunc* ButtonRightPtr;
  ButtonFunc* PreMenuCursorPtr;
  ButtonFunc* MenuCursorPtr;
  ButtonFunc* PostMenuCursorPtr;
}CURSOR_STR;

typedef struct MenuStr
{
  // more elements
  CURSOR_STR  Elements;
  // more elements
}MENU;
```

Comment: I'd say that hiding structures under `typedef`s is confusing, but that's just my opinion.

Comment: Whether to type out struct tags `struct Menustr` or use typedef is a matter of style. Typedef is by far the most common style save for in Linux, and it is also the most compatible with C++ structs and classes. Either style is ok.

Comment: (Although when declaring opaque type ADTs, the caller need not worry their pretty head about what type your ADT is using internally - which makes `typedef struct MenuStr MenuStr;` superior for programs using opaque type. We don't type `struct FILE*` when using `FILE`, do we?)

Comment: @Lundin  Since I believed that the above was the reason for a strange compilation error I made this post. I have implemented your suggestions but my problems remain. I open a new post.

Comment: @Decapod It wasn't really clear what you meant with "Now I stumble into a problem with the arguments of the pointers". I assumed it was the unknown MENU type.

Comment: @Lundin I had the impression that that was my problem. But there must be something else. Anyway your answer helped .

Comment: @Lundin I know that it's just an example, but `struct FILE*` is invalid. `FILE` is usually `typedef`'d to `struct _IO_FILE`.

Comment: @JL2210 That was the whole point - they did that on purpose so that you wouldn't have to type out `struct`. It is an opaque type and the compiler is free to handle it as it pleases internally.